# Message on category page

Tags: magento2, category

Basically I want to show static content using a block on my category menu in Magento 2.3.5. I have created a category and set Display Mode as Static Block only, Anchor set to No and Added a block from Add CMS Block dropdown, but the issue is when I try to browse this category it shows
`We can't find products matching the selection.`
How to hide this message.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message **We can't find products matching the selection.** comes from the file `/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`.

You need to override the `list.phtml` file in your custom module or theme to hide the message.

**Example:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()) :?>

// ---------------------- comment or remove the below code ------------------------------
<div class="message info empty"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div></div>

<?php else :?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
....
....
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: how to use this in my child theme?

Comment: @ishaq You need to copy the original file in your child theme and apply the changes. Copy file to the child theme `app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\listing.phtml` and make the code changes.

Comment: still, no way put this file in my custom theme but the message is still there deployed static content and cleaned and flushed cache also. put file in this location and commented the code `/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Airosoconnect/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product`

Comment: `<!-- <p class="message note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></p> -->` updated this line in listing.phtml file

Comment: Try removing the `<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?>` and remove `rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/*`, re-run static content deploy, clear the cache and check again.

Comment: Also, enable template path hint from backend and check if your template is called in front or not! Make sure you have enabled the theme from backend for your store.

Comment: Have you tried and checked as suggested above comments?

Comment: Thanks for your help but the file was `list.phtml` not `listing.phtml` after commenting the code inside `list.phtml` message disappeared.

Comment: @ishaq Thanks, I have updated the name of file in answer. Both file using the same block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.